# SAP BW to PowerBI data loading taking huge time?

Tags: azure, powerbi, sap-bw

We have a cube that contains 1.6 years of data and it is taking a long time to load. Previously we got a memory issue error, but we have increased the SAP Memory size.  Can anyone explain me any ways to troubleshoot, or any best practices that we can follow?

We are currently pulling 30-35 combinations of Dimensions and Characteristics and still its taking a lot of time, and we don’t have that amount of time in order to get the error and then act on it.

Answer (score 0):

It is the internal MDX limitation that you have to live with. In order to mitigate this, you will have to use filters or variables to restrict the return volume. If you don't mind moving data out of SAP onto Azure storage first, then you will gain much better user experience by pointing Power BI to Azure DW, Azure SQL database, or even Blob. Otherwise, you will have to be stuck with SAP bottleneck.

Because Power BI and ADF share the same underlying engine to access SAP BW, for your reference, you can check [our blog](http://www.aecorsoft.com/blog/2019/1/31/use-adf-and-ssis-to-copy-data-from-sap-bw-the-comparison-of-options) out for comparison and further explanation in context of ADF and BW integration:

Comment: But in order to apply the filters the 1.6 years of data should be present inside of the Powerbi using Import right? How can we apply a variable on SAP in order to limit the amount of data?

Comment: We do not have any issues when we import 6 Months of data. It breaks when we insert 1 year of data into the PowerBI.